# Android In App Update reports its worked however app is not updated

Tags: android

Im attempting to test Android in app updates.

I have tried using a signed production release apk and a debug production apk with a lower app version than is available on the google play store.

I always see the in app update pop up and it completes successfully.

however the app version is not updated from the play store.

```
fun checkInAppUpdate() {
    val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this@FoundationActivity)

    val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo

    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, this@FoundationActivity, APP_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnCompleteListener {
        Timber.e("In App update complete ${it.isSuccessful} - ${it.result}")
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == APP_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) Timber.e("In App Update Worked OK")
        else Timber.e("In App Update failed with $resultCode")
    }
}
```

above is the code i am using

I always see this log entry `"In App Update Worked OK"` & `In App update complete true - com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo@f0b5242`
however the app is not updated.

is it not possible to test the in app update api in this way?

is the only way to test it, to release onto the google play store?

Comment: Please see this : https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/test

Comment: can i use any app versions when carrying internal sharing?

Comment: Yes but make sure for app updating feature you need version code higher than existing installed app on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test with internal app sharing**

Use [internal app sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679) to test in-app updates by performing the following steps:

1. Make sure your test device has a version of your app installed that supports in-app updates and was installed using an internal app sharing URL.
2. Follow the Play Console instructions to [share your app internally](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679). Upload a version of your app that uses a version code that is higher than the one you already have installed on the test device.
3. On the test device, click the internal app sharing link for the updated version of your app but *do not* install the app from the Play Store page that appears after you click the link.
4. Open the app from the device's app drawer or home screen. The update should now be available to your app, and you can test your implementation of in-app updates.

Comment: I keep experiencing Something went wrong Try Again when attempting to click on the shared link

Comment: You need to add a tester email in which you want to download and test the features.

Comment: i have done that, i can get the link to share, when i click on it, i see a full size screen saying something went wrong

Comment: You enabled the Internal app sharing option from google play store?

Comment: i had not, thanks for the tip, its not easy to find how to enable app sharing though. google could make it easier.

Answer (score -1):

goto googleplay console >App bundles > New app bundles > selected version details > downloads > Assets > Signed, universal APK
Download it and upload it to your host. Only this file can replace the update through Google Play

Comment: Hi, it seems that it would only download the APK to the computer, not push a test version to the Play Store. Can you confirm that ? Thanks !